# Firefox and multiple isotope.js instances

Tags: jquery, firefox

I've got a problem with FF 36.0.1 Mac (latest version) with isotope.js.

The website is http://www.hitch.lu

I created 3 instances of a sortable animated masonry gallery that you can see clicking on menu, drinks menu, and wine list.

The 3 instances work perfectly on all browsers except Firefox who doesn't support it.

The js code is

```
/* FOOD MENUS */

$(window).load(function () {

var size = 1;
var button = 1;
var button_class = "menus-header-center-right-links-current";
var normal_size_class = "menus-content-center-normal";
var full_size_class = "menus-content-center-full";
var $container = $('#menus-content-center');

$container.isotope({itemSelector : 'div'});


function check_button(){
    $('.menus-header-center-right-links').removeClass(button_class);
    if(button==1){
        $("#filter-midi").addClass(button_class);
        $("#menus-header-center-left-title").html('Lunch menu');
        }
    if(button==2){
        $("#filter-soir").addClass(button_class);
        $("#menus-header-center-left-title").html('Dinner menu');
        }   
}


$("#filter-midi").click(function() {  $container.isotope({ filter: '.midi' }); button = 1; check_button();  });
$("#filter-soir").click(function() {  $container.isotope({ filter: '.soir' }); button = 2; check_button();  });

});


/* WINE LIST */


$(window).load(function () {

var size = 1;
var button = 1;
var button_class = "wine-header-center-right-links-current";
var normal_size_class = "wine-content-center-normal";
var full_size_class = "wine-content-center-full";
var $container = $('#wine-content-center');

$container.isotope({itemSelector : 'ul'});


function check_button(){
    $('.wine-header-center-right-links').removeClass(button_class);
    if(button==1){
        $("#filter-all").addClass(button_class);
        $("#wine-header-center-left-title").html('All');
        }
    if(button==2){
        $("#filter-white").addClass(button_class);
        $("#wine-header-center-left-title").html('White');
        }
    if(button==3){
        $("#filter-red").addClass(button_class);
        $("#wine-header-center-left-title").html('Red');
        }
    if(button==4){
            $("#filter-rose").addClass(button_class);
            $("#wine-header-center-left-title").html('RosÃ©');
            }
    if(button==5){
            $("#filter-moelleux").addClass(button_class);
            $("#wine-header-center-left-title").html('MoÃ«lleux');
            }
    if(button==6){
            $("#filter-champagne").addClass(button_class);
            $("#wine-header-center-left-title").html('Champagne');
            }   
    if(button==7){
            $("#filter-verre").addClass(button_class);
            $("#wine-header-center-left-title").html('Glass of wine');
            }
    if(button==8){
            $("#filter-bottle").addClass(button_class);
            $("#wine-header-center-left-title").html('Bottles');
            }
    if(button==9){
            $("#filter-luxo").addClass(button_class);
            $("#wine-header-center-left-title").html('Luxembourg Wines');
            }                       
}

$("#filter-all").click(function() {  $container.isotope({ filter: '.all' }); button = 1; check_button();  });
$("#filter-white").click(function() {  $container.isotope({ filter: '.white' }); button = 2; check_button();  });
$("#filter-red").click(function() {  $container.isotope({ filter: '.red' }); button = 3; check_button();  });
$("#filter-rose").click(function() {  $container.isotope({ filter: '.rose' }); button = 4; check_button();  });
$("#filter-moelleux").click(function() {  $container.isotope({ filter: '.moelleux' }); button = 5; check_button();  });
$("#filter-champagne").click(function() {  $container.isotope({ filter: '.champagne' }); button = 6; check_button();  });
$("#filter-verre").click(function() {  $container.isotope({ filter: '.verre' }); button = 7; check_button();  });
$("#filter-bottle").click(function() {  $container.isotope({ filter: '.bottle' }); button = 8; check_button();  });
$("#filter-luxo").click(function() {  $container.isotope({ filter: '.luxo' }); button = 9; check_button();  });
});



/* DRINKS MENU */


$(window).load(function () {

var size = 1;
var button = 1;
var button_class = "drinks-header-center-right-links-current";
var normal_size_class = "drinks-content-center-normal";
var full_size_class = "drinks-content-center-full";
var $container = $('#drinks-content-center');

$container.isotope({itemSelector : 'div'});


function check_button(){
    $('.drinks-header-center-right-links').removeClass(button_class);
    if(button==1){
        $("#filter-all-drinks").addClass(button_class);
        $("#drinks-header-center-left-title").html('All Drinks');
        }
    if(button==2){
        $("#filter-free").addClass(button_class);
        $("#drinks-header-center-left-title").html('Alcohol free');
        }
    if(button==3){
        $("#filter-apero").addClass(button_class);
        $("#drinks-header-center-left-title").html('Aperitif');
        }
    if(button==4){
        $("#filter-spirit").addClass(button_class);
        $("#drinks-header-center-left-title").html('Spirits');
        }                       
}

$("#filter-all-drinks").click(function() {  $container.isotope({ filter: '.all-drinks' }); button = 1; check_button();  }); 
$("#filter-free").click(function() {  $container.isotope({ filter: '.free' }); button = 2; check_button();  });
$("#filter-apero").click(function() {  $container.isotope({ filter: '.apero' }); button = 3; check_button();  });
$("#filter-spirit").click(function() {  $container.isotope({ filter: '.spirit' }); button = 4; check_button();  });
});
```

thanks for any help ! :)

Comment: Please add your relevant code here as well along with whatever markup is required to understand the problem. Your question should contain your problem in total without requirng external links.

Comment: It works fine on FF 35.0.1 (Mac).

Comment: Well, I have FF 36.0 (Mac) and it doesn't work :) and it does work on FF 35.0.1 on Windows too..